# How to get a event before Gecko downloads any file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using VB 2010 express, i have `gecko webbrowser` loaded in my project. I would to to have the option whether to download or cancel a file before the gecko browser download from the net. For instance, a webpage has several images, so i'd like to download a particular image only. How to do that?

Comment: Parsing HTML is done by using javascript, right? i wanna do from VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the HTML from the browser, you can use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load and parse the HTML.

Comment: i dont wanna parse the HTML, instead i want to add an event which triggers before geckowebbrowser downloads any file